# SQL Server : Limit rows by variable

Tags: sql-server, variables, limit

I have a code that works fine as it is. I Only want to modify one line, but I can't figure out how to do it, or is it even possible.

The code is below.

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql
N'SELECT [Brand],
         [month],
         cast(sum([Volume]) AS INT) as [Volume (t)],
         AVG(cast(sum([Volume])AS INT)) OVER (PARTITION BY [Brand]) AS [Average (t)],

        CASE WHEN (Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [month]))>@v_period
        THEN AVG(cast(sum([Volume])AS INT)) 
                    OVER (PARTITION BY [Brand] ORDER BY [month] 
                    ROWS
                    BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
                    ELSE NULL END 
                    AS [Moving Average]

FROM dw_lc_full_aggregated_1

WHERE   [year] = @v_year AND 
        [month] BETWEEN 1 AND 9 AND
        [Navision Source]=@v_navision_source AND
        [entry_type]=@v_entry_type AND
        [Brand]=@v_brand

GROUP BY [Brand],
         [month]',

    N'@v_period INT,
      @v_brand varchar (50),
      @v_year INT,
      @v_navision_source varchar (50),
      @v_entry_type varchar (50)',

    @v_period=3,
    @v_brand='xxxxxxxxx',
    @v_year=2016,
    @v_navision_source = 'HU',
    @v_entry_type='Country upload'
```

I want to modify this line to use the @v_period variable instead of "3".

BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING

Comment: no you can't use variable inside rows.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of :) Thanks! At least I'll stop searching for the solution.

Comment: you need to make some small modifications to overcome the limitation of issuing a range in the rows between x preceding and y following, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare a variable before the "execute sp_executesql" statement,
and place the command in a variable

```
DECLARE @v_period_Rows INT = 3
DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'SELECT [Brand],
         [month],
         cast(sum([Volume]) AS INT) as [Volume (t)],
         AVG(cast(sum([Volume])AS INT)) OVER (PARTITION BY [Brand]) AS [Average (t)],

    CASE WHEN (Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [month]))>@v_period
    THEN AVG(cast(sum([Volume])AS INT)) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY [Brand] ORDER BY [month] 
                ROWS
                BETWEEN '+CAST(@v_period_Rows AS NVARCHAR(10))+ ' PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
                ELSE NULL END 
                AS [Moving Average]

     FROM dw_lc_full_aggregated_1

    WHERE   [year] = @v_year AND 
            [month] BETWEEN 1 AND 9 AND
            [Navision Source]=@v_navision_source AND
            [entry_type]=@v_entry_type AND
            [Brand]=@v_brand

  GROUP BY [Brand],
          [month]'

 EXECUTE sp_executesql
 @Cmd,
  N'@v_period INT,
    @v_brand varchar (50),
    @v_year INT,
    @v_navision_source varchar (50),
    @v_entry_type varchar (50)',

  @v_period=3,
  @v_brand='xxxxxxxxx',
  @v_year=2016,
  @v_navision_source = 'HU',
  @v_entry_type='Country upload'
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have tried
    BETWEEN @v_period PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING

Failing that you could concatenate the string to become

```
'... Between' + CAST(@v_period as varchar(3)) + 'preceding ...'
```

The cast is to convert the integer to a string.